# Is there a word for a woman's female mistress?

Tags: single-word-requests

A married man's long-term female partner (outside his marriage) is his mistress.

Is there a word for a married woman's long-term female partner (outside the former female's marriage)?

Comment: Personally, although there's no formal definition to support it, I would refer to that as a mistress. All definitions specify female to male relationships but it's 2017

Comment: "Lover" has no implication of gender (beyond naive assumptions).

Comment: @HotLicks I'm not sure lover makes it clear one person is married?

Comment: Yet you say that "lover" applies to the married man's extra-marital female partner.

Comment: @HotLicks Sure, it applies, but it's not specific enough. If you disagree, please post an answer, but I'd quite like a specific word...

Comment: @HotLicks They can be lover's without the definition being exclusive. They may be lovers but not all lovers are married men and single women.

Comment: So why didn't you use "mistress" for that case?

Comment: @HotLicks yes, edited.

Comment: What's this about a former female?

Comment: @tchrist only one female is married.

Comment: Was she formerly female or formerly male?:)

Comment: *Mistress* doesn't imply that the man is married; it implies that the couple are not married to one another, and that the woman is kept by the man, as in paid. A single man can have a mistress, if he pays most or all of her living expenses in exchange for her sexual availability (and a woman, married or single, could have a mistress (female) or a gigolo (male) if she's paying for a long-term sexual relationship). The term you want might be *the other woman*, which definitely implies that the pivot of the triangle is formally committed to one woman while having illicit relations with another.

Comment: Gal Pal tells you her partner is female and they are not married. The term is a mild slur, like 'her little friend,' but not inaccurate.

Answer (score 4):

1006a wrote in a comment:

> [***Mistress***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mistress#English) doesn't imply that the man is married; it implies that the couple are not married to one another, and that the woman is kept by the man, as in paid.
>
> A single man can have a mistress, if he pays most or all of her living expenses in exchange for her sexual availability (and a woman, married or single, could have a mistress (female) or a gigolo (male) if she's paying for a long-term sexual relationship).
>
> The term you want might be [***the other woman***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/other_woman), which definitely implies that the pivot of the triangle is formally committed to one woman while having illicit relations with another.